# JAXB's unmarshaller not working on WebSphere Application Server 7 when a JAXB impl jar is included in WAR file?

Tags: java, web-applications, jaxb, websphere, websphere-7

We have a web application which connects to a web service. We use JAXB to marshall and unmarshall the soap request and response. Since we are using JDK 1.5, we included the JAXB jar in the WAR file. We were able to run it smoothly on Tomcat. However, when we deployed it on WAS 7, the unmarshaller suddenly does not work. Although we did not receive any exception/ error from unmarshalling, we cannot retrieve anything from the resulting bean. The contents of the bean is null after unmarshalling. Please note that the JAXB marshaller is working and we were able to successfully receive a response.

Comment: WebSphere 7 runs on JDK 6, so you don't need to include a JAXB distribution in your WAR. How exactly are you using JDK 1.5 with WAS 7?

Comment: I suspect that the OP developed the application using JDK 5, and was attempting to deploy it on WAS 7, not that they've somehow gotten WAS 7 to use JDK 5.

Comment: Interfering with how WebSphere implements JDK standards is never a good idea - WebSphere isn't very tolerant to practices like that. Try removing the JAXB implementation from the WAR file and give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

In websphere Please check the Class loading policy? It should be parent last.